# Remove call from stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I call the command:

```
arguments.callee
```

I get the error:

```
(node:1956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
(node:1956) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm slightly confused as to how to use arguments.callee?

What am I trying to do? I'm trying to manipulate the stack trace. I'd like to remove the latest function call (if that's even possible?).

I've read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee but it has not made me any smarter.

Comment: You cannot use `arguments.callee` to modify the stack trace anyway, and you must not use `arguments.callee` to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "modify" the call stack is by calling functions and returning from functions.

The error that you see is caused by your code running in strict mode. That means you have `"use strict"` inside this function's scope. It is unclear whether you actually need to use that or not for whatever you're trying to do.

If you're trying to get the current call stack as a string with some modifications, they you can do those modification on the string, not on the call stack:

`var stack = Error().stack;
// ... modify stack`